# Can I trigger a colorbox error

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a colorbox on [my page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

I use ajax to fetch the content for this colorbox. I performing some checks before I make the ajax request, to ensure the url is valid. If it is not, I would like colorbox to show its xhr error WITHOUT having to make an ajax call that will inevitably fail.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you do your checks, and then call the colorbox with `html` instead of a `href` option? E.g. `$.colorbox({html:"<h1>Error - " + errorMsg + "</h1>"});`

Comment: I support mccannf's answer.